# How can I sync the svn:ignore settings?

Tags: svn

How can I sync svn:ignore configuration across the machine?

eg. I have svn:ignore config with

```
*_bk
*_bak
...
```

I want to push those config to svn server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "svn:global-ignores".
See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html

Comment: My question is how to sync configuration?